# Jquery for set timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an existing jquery code that calls for showing up div contents. Here is it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'sendform.php?action=datapp',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response == 'SUCCESS') {
            $('#FormA').show();
            $('#FormB').hide();
        }
    },
```

Now, I want to add a line here that starts a timer (timeout), which shows FormC after 20 seconds. Please help.

Comment: to set timeout you want (amazingly) [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding below script for showing Formc after 20 secon.

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#FormC').show() }, 20000);
```